# Mongoose Model Options field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi I just started playing with Mongoose. It seems pretty awesome!

Now coming from a Django background, how would one implement a type of options field like:

```
STATUS_OPTIONS : [{"Open",1},{"Closed",2},{"Pending",3"}]
status: { type:String, required:true, options:STATUS_OPTIONS },
```

So that it can be set like status = Open  or something like that.

Or should this just be a normal String field and I set it accordingly in my app?

Answer (score 12):

You can constrain a Mongoose schema string field to a set of enumeration values with the [`enum`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) attribute:

```
var s = new Schema({
    status: { type: String, enum: ['Open', 'Closed', 'Pending'] }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may be trying to do is reference some possibilities, right? Probably like an `enum` field type.

Well, you may have better luck using directly an String *or* using another Schema (but if you only need the strings Closed, Open, Pending, this wouldn't be needed).